# Attach a reportviewer PDF to outlook email C#, WInForms

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services

I am trying to attach a PDF generated from the ReportViewer control to an Outlook email. I have Office 2013.

When I attempt it, the below happens (Exception: "Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again." Any ideas?

[image: Attach reportviewer to email]

```
private void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;

        byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
            "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Confirmation Letter.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            School school = School.FromID(Convert.ToInt32(booking.School));

            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = SystemData.SystemInformation.GetValue("LetterSubject");
            mailItem.To = school.MainEmail;
            mailItem.Body = SystemData.SystemInformation.GetValue("LetterMessage");
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;

            Attachment att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "Confirmation Letter.pdf");

            mailItem.Attachments.Add(att);
            mailItem.Display(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: IMO writing your code here is better than puting in an image..

Comment: @SonerGönül True, but the image shows the exception message (and yes, this could be added to the question by hand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i studied outlook.MailItem.Attatchment.add() function accept two arguments:
1. A physical path of a file which you want to attach as attachment.
2. an Mail Item object which already have a file as attachment. (that is again have a phisical file path.)

so we have to pass a physical file path for attatchment.add() methods

So in your case you have to save rendered stream as a file on your hard disk then pass the physical path of file in this method.

example: MailItem.Attachment.add(@"C:\temp\abc.pdf");

for reference go through following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx

mark answer if satisfied.

Happy coading :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, I think this will be work.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

oMsg.To = "";
oMsg.Subject = "Here comes your subject";
oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
oMsg.HTMLBody = "text body"; //Here comes your body;
oMsg.Attachments.Add("c:/yourSavedFile.pdf", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
oMsg.Display(true);
```